# String sort by character count

Tags: algorithm

Sample Data : 
input : "abcdacdc" 
Output : "cadb" 
here we have to sort strings in order of count of characters.
If the count is same for  characters. maintain the original order of 
the characters from input string.

my approach: i have used array of 26 for maintaining occurrence of all characters and sort it then print it.But while doing so i am not able to maintain order in case if two characters have same count.

please suggest any improvement or any other algo.

Comment: What you have described is extremely efficient.  It takes time O(n) to build up the frequency table, which you can then sort in O(k lg k), where k is the number of different letters you have, for a net runtime of O(n + k lg k).  I think you'll be hard-pressed to find a better approach.

Comment: but i am not able to maintain order in case if two characters have same count.

Comment: you mean, that if they have the same count, you don't want to exchange their places? If so, you could use [stable sort]:"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability".

Comment: using my algo you will get "cadb" for both "abcdacdc" and "dbcadcac" but for later case it should be "cdab"..please check..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In which language for example in c# you can do it simply as bellow:

```
var strstr = "abcdacdc";
var sortedString = new string(strstr
                              .OrderByDescending(x => strstr.Count(p=>p==x))
                              .Distinct().ToArray());
```

the algorithm is obvious (in for loop you can do the same).

**Edit:** first we sort all the character of string by their count, after that we going to use characters without their repeated items(Distinct method).

```
    private struct CharCount
    {
        public int count;
        public char ch;
    }

    List<CharCount> sortedChars = new List<CharCount>();
   for(int i=0;i<strstr.Length;i++)
   {
       if (sortedChars.FindIndex(x => x.ch == strstr[i]) < 0)
       {
         int charcount = GetCharCount(strstr, strstr[i]);
         sortedChars.Add(new CharCount {count = charcount, ch = strstr[i]});
       }
   }

   string sortedstr2 = new string(sortedChars.OrderByDescending(x => x.count).Select(x=>x.ch).ToArray());
```

You can implement `GetCharCount` method like your way, array of 26 character and ..., So above algorithms first for loop is O(n^2) and last paragraph (sorting) is O(n log (n)) in all is O(n^2). You can simply change last paragraph as a way you want (in your specific language).